# can't select parent html tags from a html string, using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I'm trying to select link tags and the tag with wrapper-main class(and what is inside it) out of this string with jQuery. but i can only select inner tags like ".text" and "#logo".
here is my javascript code:

```js
            var newDom = $(data);
            $(".main-wrapper", newDom).attr("class");
```

data is the string.
i can select ".text" and ".image".

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="">
</head>
<body>
<div class="main-wrapper">
    <div class="text">
        hi this is an example text<br>
        hi this is an example text<br>
        hi this is an example text<br>
        hi this is an example text<br>
        hi this is an example text<br>
        hi this is an example text<br>
        hi this is an example text<br>
        hi this is an example text<br>
    </div>
    <img id="logo" class="image" src="">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think they are <TextNode textContent="Text">

Comment: Beginning to think I've misunderstood the question, so maybe my answer is totally irrelevant. What's the value of `data` and what exactly are you trying to get from calling those two lines of jQuery?

Comment: data is the HTML string. I'm using $.get() to retrieve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is when you set the html, jQuery removes the html, head, and body tags. You need to use filter.

```
newDom.filter(".main-wrapper").attr("class");
```

In order for your way to work, you would need to wrap the data in a div.

```
        var newDom = $("<div>").html(data);
        $(".main-wrapper", newDom).attr("class");
```

Answer (score 1):

The `$(".main-wrapper", newDom)` syntax is equivalent to calling `$(newDom).find('.main-wrapper');` which looks for elements that match the `.main-wrapper` selector **inside** the element(s) matched by `$(newDom)` (i.e. it's only intended to find child elements).

If you want to find the `.main-wrapper` element that contains the element(s) matched by `$(newDom)` use the [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) function:

```
var elements = $(newDom).closest('.main-wrapper');
```

If you want **all** elements that are in the DOM hierarchy *above* those elements, use [`.parents()`](http://api.jquery.com/parents/):

```
var elements = $(newDom).parents('.main-wrapper');
```